# Rails optional association query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

i've been trying to solve this issue for some time now with no success :(

i have 2 model classes - ConfigurationKey and ConfigurationItem, as follows:

```
class ConfigurationKey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :configuration_items

    # this class also has a 'name' attribute
end

class ConfigurationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :app
    belongs_to :configuration_key
end
```

i would like to fetch all of the ConfigurationKeys that have a specific 'name' attribute, along with a filtered subset of their associated ConfigurationItems, in one single query.

i used the following command:

```
configuration_key = ConfigurationKey.includes(:configuration_items).where(name: key_name, configuration_items: { app: [nil, app] })
```

**but the ConfigurationKeys that don't have any associated ConfigurationItems are not returned.**

i thought the the 'includes' clause, or the explicit use of 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' would make it work, but it didn't :/

is there any possible way to do this, or do i have to use 2 queries - one to get all of the relevant ConfigurationKeys, and another in order to get all of the relevant ConfigurationItems?

thanks ;)

Comment: includes only preloads the associated model use `joins(:configuration_items)` instead.

Comment: What's your rails version?

Comment: @matanco - i tried using joins, but translates to an INNER JOIN, therefore removing the ConfigurationKey entries that don't have any association to ConfigurationItems. i would like to include those entries as well :/

Comment: @itmammoth - i'm using rails 4.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Using `includes` with `where` clause in rails 4.2 generates a LEFT OUTER JOIN query.

Please take a look at the generated sql in `rails console`.

```
$ rails c
> ConfigurationKey.includes(:configuration_items).where(name: key_name, configuration_items: { app: [nil, app] })
# Sql is displayed...
```

Probably, you'll see `LEFT OUTER JOIN`ed sql, and if so, it's correct.

Mind you, what you get via ActiveRecord is NOT equals to results from sql. It returns you `DISTINCT` results from its sql.

So, I think it's impossible to make a success in one single query.

Comment: thanks! i guess i'll be sticking to 2 queries then.. :/